# Extension Google chrome to show list of certificat

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, x509certificate, smartcard, digital-certificate

any one can help me How can I put an extension Google chrome to show list of certificat , anyboby have a solution to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any mechanism in a Chrome Extension to:

- Enumerate installed certificates.
- View certificate details for a given connection.

The closest one is `enterprise.platformKeys` API, but it exists only for enterprise-enrolled Chrome OS devices.

So, what you're trying to do is impossible using browser APIs.

You may try to use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) + some companion native application to query system certificates.